# how do you access gmail when gmail is down?

Tags: gmail, imap, pop3

Gmail is currently down. But they say I can access it through imap. How do I do this?

Comment: no longer down.

Comment: according to here it still is. http://www.google.com/appsstatus#rm=1&di=1&hl=en

Comment: Actually Troggy it's officially out of beta now, so no excuses...

Comment: Really? I guess they had that beta tag there for so long, I just got used to it. haha.

Comment: You can actually put it back (beta) with google labs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See this Google article: [IMAP or POP to access your gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/a/google.com/bin/answer.py?answer=33384).

Note: these steps must have been done ***before*** you try to access your gmail account using a POP or IMAP email client.

Comment: If someone gives me a down vote, I'd kinda like to know why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gmail offline if you install Google Gears. Outlined here http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/new-in-labs-offline-gmail.html

Update: I think the Gmail GUI (html, javascript, css) is downloaded to your machine when you install Gears and tell Google to sync, but yes you'd need to do this at least once before you lost your connection

Comment: but if gmail is down, the UI is down so you wouldn't be able to access your email even with the gmail offline feature.

Answer (score 1):

You must use an email client, such as Mozilla Thunderbird, Microsoft Outlook, Apple Mail, etc, to access GMail via IMAP or POP.